# wxWidgets Dynamically Create New Sizer after program creation, Not Rendering Properly (Newbie)

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have the following GUI, which is created with an empty sizer at the current location. The sizer is probably collapsed, as its proportion is 0, but i drew it like this so you can see it.

[image]

When you click the "+ Need" button, the program creates a new sizer with a bunch of buttons and controls, then adds it to this sizer. However they're not appearing where they should be. The new sizer and its contents is actually collapsed and in the top left corner as you can see here.

[image]

Which is obviously not what I want. However when I resize the window by just clicking and dragging one of the edges, everything pops into position:

[image]

I've tried calling every combination of ->Layout() and ->Fit() that I can think of but I just can't get it to work. This is the code that creates the GUI when program loads, called by the frame constructor. It creates "needs_sizer_wrap" which is the BoxSizer that starts out as empty and the new dynamic sizers get added to on button click. Note in the image it appears as "needsSizerWrap" but the code is actually "needs_sizer_wrap"

```
// creates the basic GUI
void MullSimple_2Frame::createGUI()
{

    // mainPanel
    main_panel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);

    // mainPanelSizer (vertical)
    wxBoxSizer *main_panel_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);

    // deckInfo (horizontal)
    // deck data along top like deck name, deck id, deck set
    wxBoxSizer *deck_info_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    main_panel_sizer->Add(deck_info_sizer, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

        // DECK ID
        // label
        wxStaticText *label1 = new wxStaticText(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "DECK ID: ");
        deck_info_sizer->Add(label1, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

        // value
        deck_info_id = new wxStaticText(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "-1");
        deck_info_sizer->Add(deck_info_id, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

        // DECK NAME
        // label
        wxStaticText *label2 = new wxStaticText(main_panel, wxID_ANY, ", NAME: ");
        deck_info_sizer->Add(label2, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

        // value
        deck_info_name = new wxTextCtrl(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "");
        deck_info_name->Bind(wxEVT_TEXT, &MullSimple_2Frame::ChangeDeckValue, this);
        deck_info_sizer->Add(deck_info_name, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

        // DECK SET
        // label
        wxStaticText *label3 = new wxStaticText(main_panel, wxID_ANY, ", SET: ");
        deck_info_sizer->Add(label3, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

        // value
        deck_info_set = new wxTextCtrl(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "");
        deck_info_set->Bind(wxEVT_TEXT, &MullSimple_2Frame::ChangeDeckValue, this);
        deck_info_sizer->Add(deck_info_set, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

        // DECK SAVED
        // can't do stuff unless the deck is saved. saving allows us to set data_vars.
        // label
        wxStaticText *label4 = new wxStaticText(main_panel, wxID_ANY, ", SAVED: ");
        deck_info_sizer->Add(label4, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

        // value
        deck_info_if_saved = new wxStaticText(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "FALSE");
        deck_info_sizer->Add(deck_info_if_saved, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());



    // progSizer (horizontal)
    // program contains 3 "columns"
    wxBoxSizer *prog_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    main_panel_sizer->Add(prog_sizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());


    // PROGRAM COLUMN 1: DECK CASTABLES

    // castables column
    wxBoxSizer *deck_casts_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    prog_sizer->Add(deck_casts_sizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

    // castables title
    wxStaticText *deck_casts_title = new wxStaticText(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "Castables", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(-1, 30), wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    deck_casts_title->SetBackgroundColour(*wxYELLOW);
    deck_casts_sizer->Add(deck_casts_title, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

    // castables content
    for ( int i = 0; i < 25; i++ )
    {
        // need to set a size so that they're small enough to all fit on my crappy laptio
        wxTextCtrl *text_ctrl = new wxTextCtrl(main_panel, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(-1, 20));
        text_ctrl->Bind(wxEVT_TEXT, &MullSimple_2Frame::ChangeDeckValue, this);
        deck_castable_inputs.push_back(text_ctrl);
        deck_casts_sizer->Add(text_ctrl, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());
    }


    // PROGRAM COLUMN 2: DECK LANDS

    wxBoxSizer *deck_lands_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    prog_sizer->Add(deck_lands_sizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

    // lands title
    wxStaticText *deck_lands_title = new wxStaticText(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "Lands", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(-1, 30), wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    deck_lands_title->SetBackgroundColour(*wxGREEN);
    deck_lands_sizer->Add(deck_lands_title, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

    // lands content
    for ( int i = 0; i < 25; i++ )
    {
        wxTextCtrl *text_ctrl = new wxTextCtrl(main_panel, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(-1, 20));
        text_ctrl->Bind(wxEVT_TEXT, &MullSimple_2Frame::ChangeDeckValue, this);
        deck_land_inputs.push_back(text_ctrl);
        deck_lands_sizer->Add(text_ctrl, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());
    }


    // PROGRAM COLUMN 3: HAND

    wxBoxSizer *hand_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    prog_sizer->Add(hand_sizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

    // hand title
    wxStaticText *hand_title = new wxStaticText(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "Hand", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(-1, 30), wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    hand_title->SetBackgroundColour(*wxBLUE);
    hand_sizer->Add(hand_title, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

    // hand content
    for ( int i = 0; i < 7; i++ )
    {
        wxTextCtrl *text_ctrl = new wxTextCtrl(main_panel, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(-1, 20));
        hand_inputs.push_back(text_ctrl);
        hand_sizer->Add(text_ctrl, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());
    }


    // PROGRAM COLUMN 4: MULL OPTS

    wxBoxSizer *mull_opts_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    prog_sizer->Add(mull_opts_sizer, wxSizerFlags(3).Expand());

    // MULL OPTS HORIZONTAL 1: MULL_OPTS_BUTTONS

    wxBoxSizer *mull_opts_but_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    mull_opts_sizer->Add(mull_opts_but_sizer, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

        // add need button
        mull_opts_but_add_need = new wxButton(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "+ Need");
        mull_opts_but_add_need->SetMinSize(wxSize(-1, 50));
        mull_opts_but_add_need->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MullSimple_2Frame::addNeedGlobal, this);
        mull_opts_but_sizer->Add(mull_opts_but_add_need, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

        // remove need button
        mull_opts_but_remove_need = new wxButton(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "- Need");
        mull_opts_but_remove_need->SetMinSize(wxSize(-1, 50));
        mull_opts_but_remove_need->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MullSimple_2Frame::removeNeedGlobal, this);
        mull_opts_but_sizer->Add(mull_opts_but_remove_need, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

        // reset all button
        mull_opts_but_reset_needs = new wxButton(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "Reset All");
        mull_opts_but_reset_needs->SetMinSize(wxSize(-1, 50));
        mull_opts_but_reset_needs->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MullSimple_2Frame::resetNeedsGlobal, this);
        mull_opts_but_sizer->Add(mull_opts_but_reset_needs, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

        // calculate button
        mull_opts_but_calculate = new wxButton(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "Calculate");
        mull_opts_but_calculate->SetMinSize(wxSize(-1, 50));
        mull_opts_but_calculate->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MullSimple_2Frame::calcNeedsGlobal, this);
        mull_opts_but_sizer->Add(mull_opts_but_calculate, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

    // needs sizer wrap, contains the needs, starts out empty
    needs_sizer_wrap = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    mull_opts_sizer->Add(needs_sizer_wrap, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

    // MULL OPTS HORIZONTAL 2: NEEDS (in a stack)
    // Make on base need we can use as a model


    // at the bottom of the main panel stretches the log output
    // fixed height so set proportion 0
    wxBoxSizer *output_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    main_panel_sizer ->Add(output_sizer, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

    log_output = new wxTextCtrl(main_panel, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(-1, 100), wxTE_MULTILINE);
    log_output->SetBackgroundColour(*wxYELLOW);
    output_sizer ->Add(log_output, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());



    main_panel->SetSizerAndFit(main_panel_sizer);
    this->Fit();

}
```

And this is the code that inserts the additional sizer when + need button is clicked

```
void MullSimple_2Frame::addNeedGUI()
{

    wxBoxSizer *need_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);

    // NEED ITEM HORIZONTAL 1: grid of filters, 4 columns

    // we'll put the same filters for every deck (for now),
    // and no custom filter ability
    std::vector<std::string> filters_in_deck;
    filters_in_deck.push_back("Land");
    ...

    // fixed 2 rows with 4 cols in each row
    wxGridSizer *base_need_filters_sizer = new wxGridSizer(2, 4, 0, 0);
    need_sizer->Add(base_need_filters_sizer, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < filters_in_deck.size(); i++ )
    {
        wxCheckBox *filter_check = new wxCheckBox(this->main_panel, wxID_ANY, myHelpFxns::ToWxString(filters_in_deck[i]));
        base_need_filters_sizer->Add(filter_check, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());
    }

    // NEED ITEM HORIZONTAL 2: line options

    wxBoxSizer *base_need_line_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    need_sizer->Add(base_need_line_sizer, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

    // line item -> "("
    wxButton *need_line_open_brack_but = new wxButton(this->main_panel, wxID_ANY, "(", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(50, -1));

    base_need_line_sizer->Add(need_line_open_brack_but, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

    // line item -> apply filters logic (any/all)
    wxComboBox *need_line_apply_filters_combo = new wxComboBox(this->main_panel, wxID_ANY);
    need_line_apply_filters_combo->Append("Any");
    need_line_apply_filters_combo->Append("All");
    base_need_line_sizer->Add(need_line_apply_filters_combo, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

    // line item -> cards to draw combo box
    wxComboBox *need_line_cards_draw_combo = new wxComboBox(this->main_panel, wxID_ANY);
    need_line_cards_draw_combo->Append("1 to Draw");
    ...
    base_need_line_sizer->Add(need_line_cards_draw_combo, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

    // line item -> source colors combo
    wxComboBox *need_line_source_colors_combo = new wxComboBox(this->main_panel, wxID_ANY);
    need_line_source_colors_combo->Append("Any");
    ...
    base_need_line_sizer->Add(need_line_source_colors_combo, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

    // line item -> cost colors combo
    wxComboBox *need_line_cost_colors_combo = new wxComboBox(this->main_panel, wxID_ANY);
    need_line_cost_colors_combo->Append("Any");
    ...
    base_need_line_sizer->Add(need_line_cost_colors_combo, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

    // line item -> cost amount combo
    wxComboBox *need_line_cost_amount_combo = new wxComboBox(this->main_panel, wxID_ANY);
    need_line_cost_amount_combo->Append("Any");
    ...
    base_need_line_sizer->Add(need_line_cost_amount_combo, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

    // line item -> specific card input
    wxTextCtrl *need_line_specific_card_input = new wxTextCtrl(this->main_panel, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString);
    base_need_line_sizer->Add(need_line_specific_card_input, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

    // line item -> ")"
    wxButton *need_line_close_brack_but = new wxButton(this->main_panel, wxID_ANY, ")", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(50, -1));
    base_need_line_sizer->Add(need_line_close_brack_but, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

    // line item -> "AND"
    wxButton *need_line_and_but = new wxButton(this->main_panel, wxID_ANY, "AND", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(50, -1));
    base_need_line_sizer->Add(need_line_and_but, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

    // line item -> "OR"
    wxButton *need_line_or_but = new wxButton(this->main_panel, wxID_ANY, "OR", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(50, -1));
    base_need_line_sizer->Add(need_line_or_but, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

    // NEED ITEM HORIZONTAL 3: NEED INLINE BUTTONS

    wxBoxSizer *base_need_buts_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    need_sizer->Add(base_need_buts_sizer, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

    wxButton *need_but_add_need_after_but = new wxButton(this->main_panel, wxID_ANY, "+");
    base_need_buts_sizer->Add(need_but_add_need_after_but, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

    wxButton *need_but_remove_this_but = new wxButton(this->main_panel, wxID_ANY, "-");
    base_need_buts_sizer->Add(need_but_remove_this_but, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

    needs_sizer_wrap->Add(need_sizer, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand().Border(wxALL, 10));
    //needs_sizer_wrap->Layout();
    //needs_sizer_wrap->Fit(need_sizer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize this until just now, but according to the documentation when you call Layout on a [top level window](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_top_level_window.html#adfe7e3f4a32f3ed178968f64431bbfe0)

> Lays out the children using the window sizer or resizes the only child
> of the window to cover its entire area.
>
> This class overrides the base class Layout() method to check if this
> window contains exactly one child – which is commonly the case, with
> wxPanel being often created as the only child of wxTopLevelWindow –
> and, if this is the case, resizes this child window to cover the
> entire client area.

So I guess calling Layout on a frame with only 1 child window won't work since that call will only try to resize the panel but the panel doesn't change size so won't try to re-layout its new children.

What seems to work is adding something like

```
this->main_panel->Layout();
```

to the end of `MullSimple_2Frame::addNeedGUI()`.  This forces a re-layout on the panel instead of the frame.

Alternately, according to the documentation you could just use a sizer the frame and only add `main_panel` to it.  But as I said in another answer, usually a sizer with only a single window doesn't make much sense.